# MSN with Python

Tags: python, msn

I have plans to create a simple bot for a game I run and have it sit on MSN and answer queries. I want to use Python to do this and googled around and found [MSNP](http://msnp.sourceforge.net/). I thought "great" and "how awesome" but it appears that it's about 5 years old and oddly enough doesn't connect to MSN as they've probably changed one or two small little things over the years.

Does anybody know of something equivalent to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything equivalent, but you can look at the source to [libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple) and roll your own without a terrible amount of difficulty.

Comment: I actually had someone else pass me their own version and this seems like the closest thing to the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're prepared to do some hard work with the original source code, you could update it to support the current version of the MSN protocol:

http://msnpiki.msnfanatic.com/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`msnlib`](http://blitiri.com.ar/p/msnlib/), which after a quick test seems to be up to date, and is quite a small and readable library in two files, with a reference implementation of a few cli chat clients and chat bots.