# How do i interface with the MSN Protocol using Python?

Tags: python, msn

I am trying to connect to the MSN network using Python.. I've done some searching and it seems like http://blitiri.com.ar/p/msnlib/ and http://msnp.sourceforge.net/ are the available libraries. However both seem very old and is there any other up to date library that i can use?

Dupplicate of : [MSN with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490929/msn-with-python)

Answer (score 2):

I might be babbling here, but I think [Python Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com) has a protocol implementation of msn.

Comment: Holy cow! You saved my life! http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/words/documentation/examples/

Answer (score 2):

libpurple at http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple

is the library that drives pidgin, and allows you to connect to MSN and others, not sure if there's a python wrapper for it.

Comment: Yeah i had previously looked at it but i shyed away from it since it didn't have a python implementation and i wanna make this a webapp.