# MSN Bot, where to begin?

Tags: msn

I want to create an MSN bot that basically monitors my incoming MSN, when one of my contacts issues a command I want to run some code and send back a text reply.

The example command format would be `!command <parameters>`

Basically I want to use MSN normally, but have replies go out when a contact issues a command via chat, I'm running Windows 7.

I don't really mind what programming language I should use, but ideally something .net related.

Can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506806/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-talk-to-msn-messenger-live-messenger) or [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490929/msn-with-python) (second one is about Python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the best bet: http://code.google.com/p/msnp-sharp/